# How change date in footer, insert only year

Tags: twig, opencart, opencart-3

Opencart 3x  How change date in footer, insert only years (html or javascript), no text ! (language/en-en/common/footer.php - $_['text_powered'] )

Answer (score 1):

The real plece where the date implements in OpenCart 3 footer is in

**catalog/controller/common/footer.php**

```
$data['powered'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_powered'), $this->config->get('config_name'), date('Y', time()));
```

This one is date

```
date('Y', time())
```

You can change 'Y' as you want using [PHP date formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php).

---

Also you can put current date directly to your **footer.twig**.

```
{{ "now"|date('d-m-Y H:i') }}
```

Comment: Thanks! I wrote like this - {{ "now"|date('Y') }} - Very good!